# Read A String Exactly As It Is in Haskell

Tags: haskell, io, io-monad

My program is something like that:

```
func = do
      text <- getLine
      return text
```

If I read line `\123\456`, the result is, naturally, `\\123\\456`.
How can I obtain  `\123\456` as the result?

Comment: No if you read `\123\456`, you read it as `\123\456`. Beware that there is a difference between the *content* of a string, and the *representation* of a string.

Comment: Note in passing that you can simplify your `func` definition to just `func = getLine`, which rather raises the question of why you need to define it as a separate action.

Comment: @RobinZigmond this is a simplified version of my actual function, where I've left only the important information

Comment: @arryn: then it is not `123456`, but `{ǈ`.

Comment: Wait, but a string `"123456"` wouldn't be represented as `"\123\456"`, at least not in Haskell. Or did you have some specific not-Haskell representation rules in mind? What are they?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I meant that I don't want '\' to be an element of my read string. For now it is, since 'return text' returns '\\123\\456'. But I do want it to be in the string as in '\123\456'

Comment: "I don't want '\' to be an element of my string" but "I do want it to be in the string" - does not compute. You're saying contradictory things.

Comment: I think you want to `read ('"' : text ++ "\"") :: String`?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem yes! Could you explain now why it works? In my intuition, it does quite the opposite, but it doesn't :)

Comment: @arryn: because `read` normally converts a string as if it was a Haskell source code fragment to a certain object (although not per se, since one can implement `Show` and `Read` freely). We thus prepend and append the string with quotes, and let it parse as if it was a string literal.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on the discussion in comments, it looks like you want to parse the string as if it was a string *literal*, except that it is not surrounded by quotes.

We can make use of of [**`read :: Read a => String -> a`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:read) here that for a string parses it as if it was a string literal to a string. The only problem is that this string literal is surrounded by double quotes (`"`).

We can thus add these quotes, and work with:

```
read ('"' : text ++ "\"") :: String
```

Not every string `text` is however per se a valid string literal, so the above might fail. For example if the `text` contains a double quote itself, that is not directly preceded by a backslash (`\`).

Comment: @arryn Is there a reason you want to `read` vs just use the string?  If you have a string `the string you want` then why `read ('"' : text" ++"\"")` instead of just use the variable `text`?